# What to return from a firebase callable function?

Tags: firebase, react-native

So I'm a little confused about returning promises in firebase callable functions. So when I return a promise directly (e.g as a response to adding a new document) it works but gives me an error in the functions log saying that the Maximum call stack size exceeded but when I add a .then() and return the document it doesn't show that error. What am I doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: I didn't say it doesn't work. It works. but I still get an error in the firebase functions log.

Comment: There's not much we can say without [seeing the minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Sharing this is the best way to increase the chance that someone can help you.